# Jasmine jQuery HTML Fixtures external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Does anybody knows if it is possible to actually use an external HTML fixture for example: http://www.stackoverflow.com?

I tried using the Jasmine-jquery extension which enables to load HTML content.
But if I try:

```
loadFixtures('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

I will get the following error:

```
Error: Fixture could not be loaded: spec/javascripts/fixtures/http://www.stackoverflow.com
```